# JAXB works with JPA, throw IllegalAnnotationsException

Tags: jpa, annotations, jaxb

I have been stacked in this place for few days. any help will be appreciated.

Here is my story:
I have a JPA entity class (ExtOffer), and Now I annotate it with JAXB annotation in order to do marshall/unmarshall by JAXB. And I also create a wrapper class(ExtOffers), which basically is a collection of  ExtOffer.
And when I call JAXBContext.newInstance(ExtOffers.class), I got an IllegalAnnotationsException:JAXB annotation is placed on a method that is not a JAXB property.

I search google and some post says that it's due to annotate @XmlElement on wrong place.
But my class has @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) annotation and only the getter method has been annotated with @Xmlelement.

below is my ExtOffer class and ExtOffers class:

//ExtOffer:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "extoffer")
@XmlType(name = "ExtOfferType")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class ExtOffer {
    public ExtOffer() {
    }
        @Id
    @Column(name = "OfferID", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 32)
    protected String offerId;

    @Column(name = "HasMoreScreenShot", nullable = false, unique = false, length = 1)
    private String hasMoreScreenShot;

        public void setOfferId(String offerId) {
        this.offerId = offerId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="OfferID", required = true)
    public String getOfferId() {
        return offerId;
    }

        public void setHasMoreScreenShot(String hasMoreScreenShot) {
        this.hasMoreScreenShot= hasMoreScreenShot;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "HasMoreScreenShot")
    public String GetHasMoreScreenShot() {
        return hasMoreScreenShot;
    }
}
```

//ExtOffers wrapper

```
@XmlRootElement(name="extoffers")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class ExtOfferWrapper {


    private List<ExtOffer> extoffers;

    public ExtOfferWrapper() {

    }

    @XmlElement(name="extoffer")
    public List<ExtOffer> getExtoffers() {
        return extoffers;
    }

    public void setExtoffers(List<ExtOffer> extoffers) {
        this.extoffers = extoffers;
    }
}
```

---

```
JAXB annotation is placed on a method that is not a JAXB property
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(nillable=false, name=HasMoreScreenShot, required=false, defaultValue=, type=class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement$DEFAULT, namespace=##default)
        at com.symbio.fuhu.appstore.jpa.entity.ExtOffer
        at public java.util.List com.symbio.fuhu.appstore.jaxb.mapping.wrapper.ExtOfferWrapper.getExtoffers()
        at com.symbio.fuhu.appstore.jaxb.mapping.wrapper.ExtOfferWrapper
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an upper case 'G'

```
@XmlElement(name = "HasMoreScreenShot")
public String GetHasMoreScreenShot() {
    return hasMoreScreenShot;
}
```

Comment: OMG. Thank you for your help and sorry for the typeing misktake....\r\n and Blaise, I really like your jaxb blog. It helps me a lot. thanks again

Comment: @yzandrew - No problem, and if there are any JAXB topics you would like to see on my blog please let me know through my contact page:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/p/contact_01.html.  Also since you are new to Stack Overflow the convention is to mark the correct answer as "accepted".  This lets other users know that you have found the answer you need.